# What requirements am I missing on App Engine for those Google libraries?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, requirements.txt

I have had all my websites on App Engine working great for years and I recently got an email saying everything I used was deprecated. I'm migrating webapp to flask, etc etc.

My new server **works locally** (finally there were just a few code changes) however the **deployed version does NOT work**.

Locally I have the cloud SDK installed and `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/:/usr/local/google_appengine` in my `PYTHONPATH`.

I import

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.api import datastore
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import db
```

What requirements.txt am I missing? I tried to add the following

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.10
google-cloud-storage==1.6.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.8.0
```

but I'm still getting errors in the deployed app: `ModuleNotFound google.appengine`. Also is there a generic way to go from google doc code example/import -> requirement? Thanks

Comment: Which runtime/environment? Your libraries suggest 1st generation standard, but that doesn't use a `requirements.txt`. Can you show the relevant portion of that email (what exactly is deprecated)? Also potentially relevant: which SDK are you using? Your paths suggest the (now deprecated) GAE SDK, not the cloud SDK.

Comment: There is no urgency to migrate from webapp2 to Flask...

Comment: They say he legacy standalone App Engine SDK (appcfg) will be deprecated in favor of the Generally Available Google Cloud SDK (Cloud SDK)

Comment: ok I see what you are saying about old paths, I see there is `from google.cloud import datastore` and ndb... a bit more migration to do, will let you know, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but a good start:

I had to migrate db to ndb
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb

this seems to necessitate to set up iam permissions
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=yourproject

The migration is not so hard, mostly replacing db with ndb, changing repeated fields (a find and replace in the code, no datastore change).
You also need to change the syntax of a few queries, this is a bit more laborious.

Regarding the "deprecated apis":

`from google.appengine.api import datastore` became `from google.cloud import datastore`

And I had to use in requirements.txt:

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.10
google-cloud-ndb==0.0.1
google-cloud-storage==1.17.0
grpcio-gcp==1.17.1
```

There are a few things that I didn't bother migrating (especially since my website is not using them that much): google oauth and memcache.
I just removed my admin page (that was using oauth), and I replaced memcache with `cachetools.LRUCache` (I used memcache to rate limit the calls on a page). Not as glamorous as a distributed cache but I didn't want to set up redis etc

End of the story: it is working locally but still not working when I deploy. After removing *everything* to just have a minimal website, it is still not working (while another project works) so I opened
 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138887166